I can't figure out how to pass a command to the windows terminal input control. C++
I am trying to write a program with which it will be possible to send a command highlighted in the browser to the terminal. I stumble on the fact that I can't figure out how to transfer any command to the terminal that my program opens. That's how I launch the terminal:
PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo;
STARTUPINFO startupInfo = { sizeof(startupInfo) };
ZeroMemory(&startupInfo, sizeof(startupInfo));
startupInfo.cb = sizeof(startupInfo);

ZeroMemory(&processInfo, sizeof(processInfo));

char cmdPath[] = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe";
CreateProcess(cmdPath, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, FALSE,
    CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, nullptr, nullptr, &startupInfo, &processInfo);


Besides being an incredible secutiry risk, cmd.exe have plenty of arguments that could be helpful. There are also other ways to launch Windows applications.

If you only want to pass one single command, the command line should be "cmd /k your_command [params...]". Passing multiple commands to the same cmd shell is possible but you will have to write them (terminated with a newline) to the hStdInput member of the STARTUPINFO structure. Or more exactly on the write end of a pipe created with the CreatePipe function

There's also the standard std::system function.

via pipe. redirect input of cmd to pipe and write commands to it. this is perfect worked

Have you checked my code? May you accept it if you concur it?

I saw your code. Your code is good. The only thing I notice is that the "gets" that you used in the code is outdated in the c++ 11 standard, instead it is better to use ``fgets(cmd, sizeof(cmd), stdin)`'.  Thank you very much.

RbMm's opinion is completely right. No matter supplying input to cmd or retrieve it's output. Pipe is an efficient method. Here is the sample:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>    

#define BUFFER_LENGTH 1024
void handle_cleanup(STARTUPINFOW,  PROCESS_INFORMATION);
DWORD WINAPI ReadPipe(LPVOID);

HANDLE CMD_WRITE, PARENT_READ, CMD_READ, PARENT_WRITE;

int CreateProcessCMD(void){
   DWORD ThreadID;
   DWORD bytes_written;
   HANDLE hProcessCMD;
   
   STARTUPINFOW PSTARTUPINFO;
   PROCESS_INFORMATION PPROCESSINFO;
   SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES SECURITYATTR;

   SECURITYATTR.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
   SECURITYATTR.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
   SECURITYATTR.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;

   if(!CreatePipe(&PARENT_READ,&CMD_WRITE, &SECURITYATTR,0)){
       printf("Could not create pipe");
       return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }
   printf("CreatePipe(PARENT_READ, CMD_WRITE) -  Success!\n");
   
   if(!CreatePipe(&CMD_READ,&PARENT_WRITE, &SECURITYATTR,0)){
      printf("Could not create pipe");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }
   printf("CreatePipe(CMD_READ, PARENT_WRITE) - Success!\n");

   ZeroMemory(&PSTARTUPINFO, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
   printf("ZeroMemory(&PSTARTUPINFO, sizeof(STARTUPINFO) -  Zeroing STARTUPINFO structure success!\n");
   
   PSTARTUPINFO.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
   PSTARTUPINFO.hStdOutput = CMD_WRITE;
   printf("CMD_WRITE ---> %x\n", CMD_WRITE);
   printf("STARTINFO.hStsOutput ---> %x\n", PSTARTUPINFO.hStdOutput);
   PSTARTUPINFO.hStdInput = CMD_READ;
   printf("CMD_READ ---> %x\n", CMD_READ);
   printf("STARTINFO.hStdsInput ---> %x\n", PSTARTUPINFO.hStdInput);
   PSTARTUPINFO.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
   PSTARTUPINFO.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
   PSTARTUPINFO.wShowWindow = SW_SHOWNORMAL;
   BOOL success = CreateProcessW(L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",
                      NULL,
                      NULL,
                      NULL,
                      TRUE,
                      NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS | CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,
                      NULL,
                      NULL,
                      &PSTARTUPINFO,
                      &PPROCESSINFO);
   if(!success){
      printf("CreateProcessW() --> Could not create process!\n");
      printf("[-] Closing program");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }
   
   printf("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe started with PID ---> %i\n", PPROCESSINFO.dwProcessId);

   HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ReadPipe, NULL, 0, &ThreadID);
   if(hThread == NULL){
      printf("CreateThread() --> Failed, Returned %i\n", GetLastError());
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }
   printf("CreateThread() --> New thread created with TID --> %i\n", ThreadID);
   Sleep(2000);
      
   while(TRUE){   
      char cmd[256];
      printf("Prompt> ");
      gets(cmd);
      strcat_s(cmd, "\r\n");
      WriteFile(PARENT_WRITE, cmd, strlen(cmd), &bytes_written, NULL);
      printf("WriteFile() --> Wrote %i bytes\n", bytes_written);
   }
   
   hProcessCMD = PPROCESSINFO.hProcess;
   switch (WaitForSingleObject(hProcessCMD, INFINITE))
   {
   case WAIT_ABANDONED :
      printf("WaitForSingleObject(hProcess, Timeout) ---> Returned WAIT_ABANDONED\n");
      break;
   case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
      printf("WaitForSingleObject(hProcess, Timeout) ---> The state of the specified object is signaled (Process has terminated)\n");
      break;
   case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
      printf("WaitForSingleObject(hProcess, Timeout) ---> Returned WAIT_TIMEOUT\n");
      break;
   case WAIT_FAILED:
      printf("WaitForSingleObject(hProcess, Timeout) ---> Failed, Returned &i\n", GetLastError());
      break;
   default:
      break;
   }
   

   handle_cleanup(PSTARTUPINFO, PPROCESSINFO);
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int main(void){

   printf("Parent PID ------> %u\n", GetCurrentProcessId());
   if(CreateProcessCMD()){
      printf("CreateProcessCMD() - Function returned EXIT_FAILURE\n");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void handle_cleanup(STARTUPINFOW startupinfo,  PROCESS_INFORMATION  processinfo ){
    if(!CloseHandle(startupinfo.hStdInput)) printf("[-] Could not close stdin handle\n");
    if(!CloseHandle(startupinfo.hStdOutput)) printf("[-] Could not close stdout handle\n");
    if(!CloseHandle(startupinfo.hStdError)) printf("[-] Could not close stderr handle\n");
    if(!CloseHandle(processinfo.hProcess)) printf("[-] Could not close process handle\n");
    if(!CloseHandle(processinfo.hThread)) printf("[-] Could not close thread handle\n");
}


DWORD  WINAPI ReadPipe(LPVOID lpThreadParameter){
     char buffer[BUFFER_LENGTH];
     
     DWORD bytes_read_from_pipe;
     while(TRUE) {
        int ret = ReadFile(PARENT_READ, buffer, BUFFER_LENGTH, &bytes_read_from_pipe, NULL);
        printf("ReadFile() --> Read %i\n", bytes_read_from_pipe);
        if(bytes_read_from_pipe>0){
           printf("%s\n", buffer);
           ZeroMemory(buffer, BUFFER_LENGTH);
           bytes_read_from_pipe = 0;
           continue;
        }
        break;
   }
}

